# Find a possible solution for $ y^{\prime \prime}+p(x) y^{\prime}+q(x) y=0 $ if $y_1(x)=\cos x$ is already a solution on $(-1,1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Q. Consider the ordinary differential equation
$$
y^{\prime \prime}+p(x) y^{\prime}+q(x) y=0,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(*)
$$
where $p, q$ are continuous functions defined on $(-1,1)$. If $y_1(x)=\cos x$ and $y_2(x)$ are solutions of this ordinary differential equation, then which of the following can be chosen for $y_2(x)$ ?

a. $1+x^2$.

b. $x$.

c. $\sin \left(x^2\right)$.

d. $x^2$.

I feel that not both $p$ and $q$ are constants, if it were, $y_2(x)=\sin x$ is the only potential solution for $(*)$. Thus, I am trying find a second solution $y_2(x)=v(x)\cdot y_1(x),$ where $v(x)=\int \frac{1}{y_1(x)^2}e^{-\int p(x)dx}dx$, but, how to proceed with an arbitrary continuous function $p(x)$?

Further, I am always in trouble while considering $p(x)$ in particular, due to the quotient $\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$ inside the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $y_2$ is a solution such that $y’_2(0)=0$ and define $f(x)=y_2(x)-y_2(0)y_1(x)$. Then $f$ is a solution of the same differential equation with $f(0)=f’(0)=0$ and consequently $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. That is $y_2$ is proportional to $y_1$.

Now, three of the proposed functions have a derivative that vanishes at $0$ and they are not proportional to $\cos$, so they are to be excluded. The remaining solution is $x\mapsto x$ so the answer is $b.$

Answer (score 1):

$$y^{\prime \prime}+p(x) y^{\prime}+q(x) y=0$$
Put $y_1=\cos x$ then you deduce from the DE  that $q(0)=1$.

So option $a$ is not possible because for $y_2=1+x^2$ at $x=0$
$$y^{\prime \prime}+p(x) y^{\prime}+q(x) y=0$$
$$y^{\prime \prime}(0)+p(0) y^{\prime}(0)+q(0) y(0)=0$$
$$2+p(0)\times 2 \times 0+1 \times 1 \ne 0$$
Do the same for option $c$ and $d$ so you are left with option $b$ and  $y_2=x$. This is a possible solution but you must have $p(0)=0$.